# jquery map function doesn't see new DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, dom

I am occasionally running a JS routing that needs to obtain data attributes from rows within a table.   A simplified version of this code is as follows:

```
var dataList = $('#tableName tr').map(function() {
    return $(this).data("data_attribute");
}).get();
dataList=dataList.join(',');
console.log("Found following values: "+dataList);
```

The issue is that these attributes change sometimes and the above code doesn't see them or apparently any other changes in the DOM.

Is this going t need a total rewrite?  Does anyone have a known alternative method or can you make jQuery see the DOM changes somehow?

There's a JS fiddle here to illustrate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/arkid77/0pxk5bm4/6/

Comment: I can't think of any reason why it wouldn't see dynamically added elements. Did you assign `$('#table tr')` to a variable instead of using it literally? You need to update the variable after you change the DOM.

Comment: I think you may have simplified the code too much, so you lost whatever is causing the problem. Please post enough code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Where is this code executed? Where are the data attributes updated? There's not really enough info here to debug it.

Comment: A new JS fiddle thats working is here: https://jsfiddle.net/arkid77/0pxk5bm4/6/